# How do I get the rate limit headers for discord in python?

Tags: python, discord

I've read in the documentation about the rate limits discord puts on bots and the optional HTTP response headers containing the rate limit encountered during the request. However, I don't know how to get that information about my own bot. I can't find anything online about this either.

Documentation: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits

Answer (score 1):

To get access to the JSON holding all of the information just use the function

```
x = requests.get("https://discord.com/api/v6/*APPLICATION ID*", headers={"Authorization": *BOT TOKEN*})
```

application id can be found in the discord developer portal where your bot is located, and you should already have access to the bot token. Also I don't think it really tells you the information on limits unless you have already exceeded them from what I know (very well could be wrong).

Comment: Hi so I've tried this and after printing x.json() I got {'message': '404: Not Found', 'code': 0}. Also, just checking I needed to but the bot token as a string as well (otherwise it chucks an error)

Comment: https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2370 After searching the code you provided I saw this issue. After trying it I got this message: {'message': 'Bots cannot use this endpoint', 'code': 20001}